# Resharper: How to format multiline methods using parentheses as curly braces and indented parameters?

Tags: c#, resharper, indentation, code-formatting

I'm new to Resharper and I can't seem to find an option to format multi-line method declarations like this:

```
public void SomeMethod
(
    int parameter1,
    string parameter2
);
```

Instead, I get this:

```
public void SomeMethod
    (
        int parameter1,
        string parameter2
    );
```

Is there a way to do it **automatically** on code cleanup?

Comment: If you delete the last ; and retype it, it will usually correct the indentation.

Comment: @AdamDrummond, this is usually only the case when VS and R# are both active (in terms of automatic formatting) and not configured to do the same formatting.

Comment: @Lucero so if Resharper has a different option set for it, that action will do nothing?

Comment: @AdamDrummond, oh it will - but depending on the trigger one or the other will be applied, causing the format to change between the two settings.

Comment: Hmmm... it seems to correct the indentation of the parameters, but the parentheses stay in the same place. Anyway, I was hoping for an automatic method that I can use with code cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Options| C# | Formatting Style | Braces Layout.

From there you can change the rules for the indentation.  For Regular methods mine is set to At next line (BSD style).

Comment: Yep, tried that. But in this case I'm using parentheses, not braces, so unfortunately this doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

In ReSharper -> Options

C# -> Formatting Style -> Other -> Indentation,

Set: Continuous line indent multiplier to 0